# pwr package not returning delta value when put in as NULL

Tags: r, statistics

```
library(pwr)
```

I want to calculate the minimum cohen's d I can expect from a t-test given I know the proposed n, power, significance level, design (one sample) and that it's a two tailed hypothesis test, but it's not returning a d value. I have entered it as `NULL` as specified in the documentation as default is to keep this as `FALSE`. Also tried it without specifying the `d` value.

```
effect <- pwr.t.test(d = NULL,
                      n = 30,
                      power = .99,
                      sig.level = .16,
                      type = "one.sample",
                      alternative = "two.sided")
```

Is there something I am missing? I have also tried pwr.p.test for one sample t test but no luck.

Comment: I cannot reproduce.  Running your code gives output as expected and `d = 0.6933506`.  Try restrating your session.

Comment: I have, but it's not producing a d value

Comment: At the risk of asking the obvious, you did follow your statement above with `print(effect)`?

Comment: so sorry, been away. No I did not and easy to forget how useful print function can be, but will try that out thanks :)